# Drupal6: Administer Menu Gone

Tags: menu, drupal-6, roles

In Drupal 6, the administer menu is gone. The super user (`uid = 1`) can see it, but the Admin role, that has the correct permission, does not. If a user with the Admin role were to go to the pages, they could access them (like `nodes/add/content_type` or something), but there is no menu. (So hypothetically, the site could be administered by Admins by going direcly to URLs instead of using menus.)

Why could this be happening? I've flushed the caches.

The Admin role has the `Menu Module >> Administer Menu` permission. The Authenticated user has this role, too (as a test), but it still doesn't work.

**UPDATE:** Clarification of above: if an Admin navigates to `/admin`, he will get an `Access Denied` error.

This is what `print_r(debug_backtace());` yields:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
     Array ( [file] => /home/sitename/public_html/subdir/index.php 
             [line] => 27 
             [function] => drupal_access_denied
             [args] => Array ( ) ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the admin user can see the menu, the you just need to go to admin/user/permissions, scroll to menu module, and make sure that administer menu is selected for the Admin role.

Comment: I had set this for the Admin role, and, as a test, for Authenticated User. It still does not work.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm assuming it's enabled in admin/build/menu-customize/navigation, since uid=1 can see it, so the only other thing to check is to make sure that access administration pages is checked under system modules in permissions. Other than that... no idea :( sorry.

Comment: oh yeah, the `access administration pages` was not enabled. wow. good for me.